# CMake Error: Could not find openSSL or GCrypt

Tags: windows, openssl, cmake

I'm trying to use CMake in order to get libssh binaries for Windows.
I have Windows 7 OS and VS 2010.
I installed OpenSSL and set in CMake the entries OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR and OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR. After that, I get the following error:

```
Could NOT find NSIS (missing:  NSIS_MAKE)
Could NOT find OpenSSL (missing:  OPENSSL_LIBRARIES)
Could NOT find GCrypt, try to set the path to GCrypt root folder in the system variable GCRYPT_ROOT_DIR (missing:  GCRYPT_INCLUDE_DIR GCRYPT_LIBRARIES)
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:57 (message):
   Could not find OpenSSL or GCrypt
```

Any help will be welcome...
Thanks in advance

Answer (score -2):

Worked out after I set the entries SSL_EAY_DEBUG and SSL_EAY_RELEASE.

Comment: This isn't a useful response. What did you set them to?